# Does log4j requires JSF jars?

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf, log4j

I build a REST web service (using JAX-RS, Spring, Spring JMS, and ActiveMQ). I'm surprised that when I deploy it to Tomcat 5.5.23 I get an exception that JSF jars are required?!

```
Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4216)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
```

The web service was working fine until I added log4j functionality in different classes, here's my log4j.properties file (I placed it in WEB-INF/classes):

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, S

log4j.logger.com.dappit.Dapper.parser=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.w3c.tidy=FATAL

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
#  The following properties configure the console (stdout) appender.
#  See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/docs/api/index.html for details.
#
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
log4j.appender.S = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.S.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.S.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Does this error go away when you remove only the log4j.properties file.

Comment: If I do it, I get the following error (when starting tomcat):


log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.sax).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Aug 17, 2010 12:24:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart

Comment: If i remove it, I get the following error (when starting tomcat):


    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.sax).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    Aug 17, 2010 12:24:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
    SEVERE: Error listenerStart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a classloader hierarchy issue.  You should enclose log4j in your WAR file, not put it in the shared libraries of Tomcat.

Also, I had some problems with Tomcat 5.5 that was fixed in Tomcat 6.0.  You may want to consider upgrading.

Comment: It was some kind of class conlfict issue:
MyEclipse automatically placed the JSTL and JSF jars in my lib path, in addition I noticed that there's a class "Logger" in JSTL (org.apache.taglibs.standard.lang.jstl.Logger), once I declared my logger classes using the full apache log4j package name (org.apache.log4j.Logger) it worked!!

Answer (score 2):

I would expect to see this if you have a reference to `org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener` in your web.xml, like:

```
<listener>
     <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Can you verify that there is no such element?

Comment: I had it removed, but i'm still getting:



log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.sax).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Aug 17, 2010 12:43:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart

Comment: Did you add your log4j.properties file back? Do you have the log4j jar WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: yes I did add the .properties file back, but I don't have the log4j jar in my app's web-inf because I noticed there's a log4j-1.2.8.jar under TOMCAT_HOME/shared/lib. Do I need to add it to my WEB-INF folder?

Comment: Give it a try - I have a faint recollection of having problems with log4j unless the jar was actually in the webapp's WEB-INF/lib folder on Tomcat.

Comment: I did, but now i'm getting:
Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener

If I add all the JSF/JSTL jars that MyEclipse referenced on my development machine, I get this exception:


Error configuring application listener of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ExpressionFactory


I just don't get it, why is JSF being used?

Comment: If you are using MyEclipse, did you do the 'Add JSF capabilities...' thing described here http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/jsf/? Sounds a little like the IDE might doing things behind the scenes

Comment: It indeed look much like that you've either accidently or unawarely added JSF (Faces) facets yourself while creating MyEclipse web project. Just don't do that :) Rightclick project, check Project Facets and uncheck the JSF/Faces ones (and if necessary manually remove the autogenerated JSF related entries from `web.xml`).

Answer (score 1):

Make the following dependencies(if present) in maven as provided: 
javax javaee-api 6.0     scope : provided

javax.servlet javax.servlet-api 3.0.1 scope : provided